# Implementing traffic conditions in TORCS

Tags: game-design, simulations

I am working on a project about "Effects of Traffic conditions and Track Complexity on Car Driving Behavior".

**Is it possible to implement traffic in TORCS, or should I use another car simulator?** By the word "*traffic*" I mean there are cars running on both tracks in both directions and I can detect the distances, direction and speed of these cars. Depending on this information I can decide whether I should slow down, speed up and calculate the correct timing to overtake.

Answer (score 1):

Since [TORCS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/torcs/) is an open source project, yes, of course it's possible to implement traffic. You can implement anything you like by changing the code entirely.

If it's reasonable or not is another question entirely. And, it's one only you have the best answer for.

It sounds like your project is more research oriented. And thus, doesn't need to have fancy graphics like a racing simulator provides (yes TORCS does more, I'm speaking more about other simulators). Ideally, if you want something that's more deterministic, you'd have your simulation able to run without any interface whatsoever. If you'd like to have an interface, it can be a very simple one. As simple as having each car represented by a single pixel.

Get your part of the simulation working before worrying about how pretty it looks. It's certainly worth looking further into TORCS to see how difficult it would be to modify for this purpose, to give you more robust simulations, but you might want to get something simple working first.